# How can I improve the string matching code to read 'Jakarta Barat' instead of 'Jakarta' in my Python script?

Tags: python, string, loops, oop, nested-loops

Python String Problem : I have to mathing the data from tweet to the string on my csv file

I have try the code to do matching the tweet and the csv file
here is the code :

```
def check_keterangan(row):
    tweet = row['Tweet'].split()
    city = set(kota['kabko'])
    ganti = dict(zip(kota['kabko'], kota['kabko']))
    for kata in tweet:
        if kata in city:
            return ganti[kata]
    return row['kota']
```

the explanation :
variable tweet : take the row the than contains the target matching (kota like : "Jakarta Barat"
the sample of tweet is : "murni sumbangan instansi pemerintah kerja buzzerrpberbagi membantu masyarakat terdampak corona covid 19 daerah kamal **jakarta barat** palti west tacubz 03 nakula cintada17 ferdinandhaean2"

the problem is my code can not read the string "jakarta barat" but only read "jakarta"
can you improve the looping of my code so my code can read the kota as "jakarta barat"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to improve my looping, because my code still have a bug if the input tweet have the city who has more than one word like "jakarta barat" my code is only can read as "jakarta"

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the city and even the city contains 2 words.

kata will be **Jakarta Barat**

kata.lower() will be **jakarta barat**

tweet.lower() will be **murni sumbangan instansi pemerintah kerja buzzerrpberbagi membantu masyarakat terdampak corona covid 19 daerah kamal jakarta barat palti west tacubz 03 nakula cintada17 ferdinandhaean2**

And it will find the substring

```
def check_keterangan(row):
    tweet = row['Tweet'].split()
    city = set(kota['kabko'])
    ganti = dict(zip(kota['kabko'], kota['kabko']))
    for kata in city:
        if kata.lower() in tweet:
            return ganti[kata]
    return row['kota']
```

Comment: `tweet = row['Tweet'].split()` results in `tweet` being a list. So `tweet.lower()` won't then work.

Comment: right right, then no lower there